# RELATED,ESTABLISHED state in iptables

Tags: iptables

What do the words 'RELATED' and 'ESTABLISHED' individually signify in RELATED,ESTABLISHED state in iptables?

Comment: See : http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RELATED - packets, which is new - but "related" to alredy established connection.
For example - you send me message about football match results. I replayed to you, but send message about my new sweater. So - we both use skype (for example), at the same time. But - we spoke about different things. Best of all RELATED regarding to FTP protocol - it's opening few connections, but from host-to-host with same protocol type.

ESTABLISHED - when we speak in same chat about same issue. Good example can be VPN - client opening connection to server, and packets move via this "tunnel ".

And NEW one - when you I got sound alarm from my skype, which signals to me that I have new incoming message.

Answer (score 2):

They indicate packets on related or established connections, e.g. the connection to the ftp-data port when a file request has been performed via FTP, or the second and subsequent packets on a HTTP 1.1 keepalive connection.